# Show image in a div tag with it's real size using jquery/css/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an asp.net mvc3 application. My views use razor but I think this doesn't matter now. I needed an image gallery where you can delete and upload image and some other demands which I couldn't find on the galleries that I saw at the net so I ended up making my own implementation.

I have problem with showing the image in real size from the thumbs in the gallery.I made a little script to show the essence of the problem :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.thumb-image { cursor: pointer;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="Forest.jpg" class="thumb-image" alt="Forest"  height="300px" width="300px"/>
<script>
$('.thumb-image').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();//
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This little script I used just to check if I can reach the image from the DOM (or more exactly how to reach it - I knew it's possible, it's just me being with very basic skills in JS/jQuery).

So my question is this - `Forest.jpg` is an image on my desktop, originally it's `3550x2377px`. Now I use image from my desktop - originally the images are taken from a server, but even then I don't keep any cache. The style for the `<img>` tag is just to achieve some sort of thumbnail effect but the image is downloaded to the client at its full size. So is it possible to show this image in its real size in some `<div> tag` for example (in this case `3550x2377px`) without making additional call to the server or at my case - passing again the path to the image, but using the image from the thumbnail, which is downloaded at it's full size or after I make the CSS change for `width` and `height` it's not possible to get the real dimensions again?

Comment: So essentially you want to show the big image if you click on the image tag with the smaller dimensions?

Comment: Yeah. Just like in standard image gallery - show small icons/thumbs and let the user the ability to see the image in a real size. It's all about tech drawings so I don't want to do any resizing when the user click for the real size image because I'm not sure if it won''t hurt their work. So I just want to show the image with the size it was uploaded once from the user, but escape the double call to server if it's possible. So in short - yes, you are correct.

Comment: You really should create some actual thumbnails on the server. Imagine your image is 1mb in size, you are forcing the user to download that even if they do not click the image. Now imagine 10 of those on your page, or 10 clicks to 10 separate pages. You're hurting there bandwidth and download times, and costing yourself more bandwidth.

Comment: I know, but it's very specific, the traffic will be low, maybe I'll have to do what you say but now more important is to make it with or without real thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using height and width attributes use a class and use jquery to remove/hide the class

```
.thumbimage {
height:300px;
width:300px;
}

$('.thumb-image').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('thumbimage');
});
```

Comment: Lol, nice, jQuery is such fun. Is there where to keep `cursor: pointer` while toggle?

Comment: thanks Leron to target the image all the time I would use a different class or css statment for example div img { cursor:pointer} - in this case any image within a div will always have a pointer cursor but it would probably be best to put an ID on the image containers and target it that way #idname img {cursor:pointer} ... hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is a bad practice to use an `img` that refers to a big image file when you only need to show a small version of it. That is because the browser still has to load the big version of the image completely, which will be slow, and then only shows it in a small version which usually is not looking good.

The best way for the user of the site would be to generate a small version of the big image that you show in your `img` tag and then only load the big version if a user clicks on that. Like this your site will be rendered much faster and will use less bandwith etc.

This would be done like this:

```
<img src="Forest_thumb.jpg" class="thumb-image" alt="Forest" />
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.thumb-image').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('<img src="Forest.jpg" class="full-image" alt="Forest" />')
            .appendTo('.your-div');
    });
});
</script>
```

In your case using the big image as thumb by specifying width and height the browser already fetched the big image, so if you use the big image afterwards it will not be fetched again from your server but from the browser cache.

If you want to keep your big image as thumb and show the big image when you click on the `img`-Tag you can for example just remove the width and height from your img tag with jQuery like this:

```
$('.thumb-image').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the more complete answer by now. I really may think for caching the images on the server but for now I need something working. Also, it's not exactly a site, it's application that will be used a lot of time offline and go online just to transfer data with service where I need to pass the original images so the need of server side chaching is doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

In your click() function, if you want to resize image to original size:

```
$(this).removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height");
```

Or if you want to have copy of the image with original size:

```
var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).load(function() {

    // your image dimensions:
    pic_real_width = this.width;
    pic_real_height = this.height;

    // show full-size image
    $('body').append(img);
});
```